# Connecting to Vertica database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, vertica

I'm trying to connect to a Vertica database using SQLAlchemy.

I came across and installed a Vertica dialect at https://github.com/jamescasbon/vertica-sqlalchemy. I've also installed pyodbc.

Using a basic tutorial at http://www.pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-orm-examples/, I have the following code snippet :-

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, String, Integer, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

engine = create_engine(sa.engine.url.URL(drivername='vertica+pyodbc',
       username='<username>',password='<password>',
       host='<host>',database='<db name>',))


session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

When this runs I get the traceback :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3291, in    create_all
tables=tables)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1546, in _run_visitor
with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1539, in    _optional_conn_ctx_manager
with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1729, in contextual_connect
self.pool.connect(),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 332, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 626, in _checkout
fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 433, in checkout
rec = pool._do_get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 945, in _do_get
return self._create_connection()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 278, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 404, in __init__
self.connection = self.__connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 527, in __connect
connection = self.__pool._creator()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 95, in connect
connection_invalidated=invalidated
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 185, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 89, in connect
return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 376, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') None None
```

The last line I guess is the one to look at :--

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') None None
```

Connections can be made to the database from other clients so the credentials etc are fine.

I'm not sure what is causing this - can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to download and install actual [Vertica drivers](https://my.vertica.com/). You'll have to register for an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is using unixODBC to connect to Vertica. You need to [install the drivers](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/InstallingDrivers/InstallingODBCDriversOnLinuxSolarisAIXAndHP-UX.htm%3FTocPath%3DProgrammer%27s%20Guide%7CHP%20Vertica%20Client%20Libraries%7CInstalling%20the%20HP%20Vertica%20Client%20Drivers%7CInstalling%20the%20Client%20Drivers%7C_____2) and [set up a DSN](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/InstallingDrivers/CreatingAnODBCDSNForLinuxSolarisAIXAndHP-UX.htm)

You should be able to connect with these parameters.  This is what worked for me in my previous SQLAlchemy / Vertica project.  Also, if this doesn't work, I would make sure it is configured properly and that you can connect using isql (comes with unixODBC).

```
drivername='vertica+pyodbc',
username='myuser',
password='mypassword',
host='hostname',
database='DBNAME',
```

You can also do this for a DSN connection:

```
engine = create_engine('vertica+pyodbc://username:password@mydsn')
```

Comment: Thanks - I've created the DSN and have the Vertica driver. Assuming it's called "test", how do you refer to it in the "create_engine" call? I assume it's referenced there.

Comment: Could you please share your DNS settings? I've tried to follow instructions from the link with no luck.

Comment: @Marigold What's the error message you are receiving? Have you been able to connect via `isql`?

Comment: Thaanks @woot, I managed to get it all together with tutorials from all over the internet. Added another answer just in case someone runs into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is setup for Ubuntu 14.04 assuming you have a driver installed in `/opt/vertica/` and using HP Vertica from this Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/sumitchawla/vertica/ and have https://github.com/jamescasbon/vertica-sqlalchemy.

**/etc/vertica.ini**

```
[Driver]
ErrorMessagesPath = /opt/vertica/lib64/
ODBCInstLib = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
```

**~/.odbc.ini**

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
vertica = "My Database"

[verticadsn]
Description = My Database
Driver = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
Database = docker
Servername = 127.0.0.1
UID = dbadmin
PWD =
```

If you did everything right, this command should return your version of Vertica

```
engine = create_engine('vertica+pyodbc://dbadmin:@verticadsn')
engine.connect().scalar('select version()')
```

Comment: i think writing `dbadmin:` in `engine = create_engine('vertica+pyodbc://dbadmin:@verticadsn')` overwrites the UID and PWD in the .odbc.ini file. 
`engine = create_engine('vertica+pyodbc://@verticadsn')` works just fine