# Error while Connecting to Vertica database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know this question has already been answered in this post [Connecting to Vertica database using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832487/connecting-to-vertica-database-using-sqlalchemy)

But the answer posted does not solve my purpose

Here is what I am doing

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pymysql
import pyodbc
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import sqlalchemy_vertica
engine=sa.create_engine(sa.engine.url.URL(
    drivername='python+vertica',
    username='xxx',
    password='xxx',
    host='production-xxx-cluster-with-failoverxxx',
    database='xxxx',
))
```

There is no issue with connection to vertica as I can connect via pyodbc. Also the answer in [Connecting to Vertica database using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832487/connecting-to-vertica-database-using-sqlalchemy) says this only works with Unix ODBC . I am in a mac environment and have the mac ODBC drivers properly installed .  The error that I am getting is :

```
/Users/sushmit.roy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.pyc in get_dialect(self)
    115         if '+' not in self.drivername:
    116             return self.get_dialect().driver
--> 117         else:
    118             return self.drivername.split('+')[1]
    119 

/Users/sushmit.roy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.pyc in load(self, name)
    192         raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
    193             "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" %
--> 194             (self.group, name))
    195 
    196     def register(self, name, modulepath, objname):

NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:python.vertica
```

I am suspecting this is an installation issue since it is not able to find the required package . Can anybody help me triage this one?

Also to provide more information I am using anaconda Python2.7.9 version and all my packages are updated. I can see the sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy_vertica packages in the required folder (i.e) //Users/sushmit.roy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages