# Airflow with Vertica as metadata backend

Tags: python, airflow, vertica

I am trying to set up airflow with Vertica Database as metadata backend. Facing the below error when I try to run airflow initdb.

Following is the configuration used in `airflow.cfg` file.

```
sql_alchemy_conn = vertica+vertica_python://username:password@host:port/dbname
```

Error msg received :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 1131, in initdb
    db.initdb(settings.RBAC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 106, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 376, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 298, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 173, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 92, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 82, in run_migrations_online
    compare_type=COMPARE_TYPE,
  File "<string>", line 8, in configure
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 822, in configure
    opts=opts,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 218, in configure
    return MigrationContext(dialect, connection, opts, environment_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.impl = ddl.DefaultImpl.get_by_dialect(dialect)(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 71, in get_by_dialect
    return _impls[dialect.name]
KeyError: 'vertica'
```

Please let me know if this configuration is supported(`airflow` + `vertica` as backend). Any help or input regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any database as a backend.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/initialize-database.html

```
 As Airflow was built to interact with its metadata using the great
 SqlAlchemy library, you should be able to use any database backend
 supported as a SqlAlchemy backend. We recommend using MySQL or
 Postgres.
```

And to be able to connect Vertica, you should install and configure unixODBC,

And  you can find the rest below,

[Connecting to Vertica database using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832487/connecting-to-vertica-database-using-sqlalchemy)